# java sunspots no serial port available (ttyACM0)

Tags: java, 64-bit, debian, sunspot

I am trying to work with sun sunspots on 64 bit debian, but whatever I do I get no where. I have searched various errors but with the actual sunspot forum down I am having no luck.

I tried adding port= ttyACM0 to .sunspot.properties, but then I get an error that is about the same. The error message below is from trying to get sunspot info from ant. I have put all the text in there just in case it is useful but the actual error message is    [java] Please wait while connected Sun SPOTs are examined...
     [java] No serial port available
     [java] Java Result: 255

and the whole text shebang was

```
    Buildfile: /home/andrew/SunSPOT/sdk/Demos/AirText/build.xml

   -pre-init:

   -do-init:

   -post-init:

   -warn-jar-file:

    init:

    -override-warning-find-spots:

    -prepare-conditions-for-find-spots:

    -find-shared-basestation:

    -run-spotfinder:
         [exec] Using Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) to probe Sun SPOTS...

    -check-spotfinder-result:

    -decide-whether-to-run-spotselector:

    -run-spotselector:
         [java] Please wait while connected Sun SPOTs are examined...
         [java] No serial port available
         [java] Java Result: 255

    -collect-spotselector-result:

    -clean-up-spotselector-output-file:

   -spotselector-fail:

    BUILD FAILED
    /home/andrew/SunSPOT/sdk/ant/find-spots.xml:367: Spotselector failed or was      cancelled

   Total time: 8 seconds
```

Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem.

This document explains the problem at the bottom half of page 140: 
http://www.sunspotworld.com/docs/Yellow/SunSPOT-Programmers-Manual.pdf

This document explains how to fix it on page 29:
http://www.cs.umanitoba.ca/~comp4430/Documents/InstallationInstructions.pdf

I'm pretty new to Linux, so basically, what I did was typing:

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyACM0

sudo chmod 777 /var/lock
```

This is not a good solution, but it works! At least, it did for me.

Please notice that the `sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyACM0` command must be run every time you connect the SPOT.

Comment: While this effectively works, and you don't need to do it if you sudo any ant command, I'd like to know the reason. Maybe we should add our normal user to a group that is allowed to write to /dev/ttyX?